# Tkinter only displays last three lines of the paragraph

Tags: python, tkinter

Tkinter is not displaying the full paragraph in a window

My code:-

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import tkinter as tk  


dinosaur = 'dinosaur'

url = ('https://html.duckduckgo.com/html?q='+dinosaur)

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')
a = soup.body.b
print(a)

for i in soup.find_all('a', class_='result__snippet'):
    print(i.get_text(separator=' - ', strip=True))
    abc = (i.get_text(separator=' - ', strip=True))



    
    
root = tk.Tk()
S = tk.Scrollbar(root)
T = tk.Text(root, height=4, width=50)
S.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
T.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.Y)
S.config(command=T.yview)
T.config(yscrollcommand=S.set)
T.insert(tk.END, abc)
tk.mainloop()
```

But it displays the whole paragraph in terminal though

can anyone point out the mistake i am making?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following part of the code should be as follows:

```
abc=""
for i in soup.find_all('a', class_='result__snippet'):
    print(i.get_text(separator=' - ', strip=True))
    abc += (i.get_text(separator=' - ', strip=True))
```

The `+=` operator concatenates the string so that you have the full text, and not only the last iteration of the loop.

### Note

Tcl does not support all the characters. Therefore, depending on the character, it would not be possible to be printed.

To avoid this problem, add the following lines:

```
abc_clean = ""
char_list = [abc[j] for j in range(len(abc)) if ord(abc[j]) in range(65536)]
for j in char_list:
    abc_clean+=j
```

And then:

```
T.insert(tk.END, abc_clean)
```

Comment: abc += (i.get_text(separator=' - ', strip=True))
NameError: name 'abc' is not defined

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot the line above the for-loop. Now it is fixed.

Comment: So how can i cut those characters ?

Comment: I provided the lines that clean the string of strange characters